# Google's Huawei ban, how will this hit Huawei, since Android is open source?

Tags: google, huawei, open-source

So, with the latest news of [Google blocking Huawei from Android updates](https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/may/19/google-huawei-trump-blacklist-report), what does this actually mean?

Since Android is open source (via [AOSP](https://source.android.com/)), Huawei should be perfectly able to continue using Android, and even create their own derivative from it, as the article says.

The only thing that Google could do, is disallowed their Apps suite, with the Play Store (as again per the article). But Huawei should be in a strong enough position to build their own app store and provide their own apps. (Could they use [Open GApps](https://opengapps.org/)?)

In the end, this will force Huawei into a position as a strong competitor to Google, especially, but not exclusively, in their China home market.

**So, how should this ban actually hurt Huawei?**

Notes:

- To keep this question focused on Android, I explicitly exclude the use of what Huawei calls their "Backup OS", but just focus on which parts of Android could be "banned".
- Also, I would expect answers to apply to any Android phone manufacturer, not Huawei specifically (Or is there something special about Android on Huawei devices I did miss?)

Comment: Building you own store is easy. Plenty of stores are out there. Building replacement APIs of Play Services (a plethora of useful apps are dependent on Play Services APIs, including the safetynet API upon which financial apps depend) can be very hard. And that wouldn't guarantee a smooth user experience either. Huawei furthermore cannot build an app ecosystem around itself. Microsoft with millions at disposal tried to build the app ecosystem for Windows phone, and then packed up from this business a few years later.

Comment: XDA has a good article here: https://www.xda-developers.com/google-revoke-huawei-android-ban-blacklist/

Comment: @Firelord A great article indeed. But I still have a hard time understanding why they can not simply go the ASOP+EMUI route, even without preinstalled GApps. Installing OpenGAPPS with LineageOS was easy enough for me, with a little help this should be doable for anyone.

Comment: "*with a little help this should be doable for anyone.*" I know some non-tech-savvy users who don't understand and are afraid to even touch the Android's Settings app... I'm not sure if they are comfortable enough to access Recovery mode and flash Open GApps...

Comment: I was asking myself the exact same question. Does anyone know what is the procedure for a vendor to ship its Android version with the playstore pre-installed ? (because I guess that's what their collaboration with Google leads to. It's to have access to the playstore, hence all the Google apps)

Comment: @ArthurAttout This is a good question - I suggest you just ask it separately.

Comment: Its been 2 years since this post, I had [a similar question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/247577/376422) and was redirected to this post. But there are not much details in this post. If anyone has any new info about this then please do share them. Anyway I am gonna do a bit more research on this buy I hope @Marcel has some more insight about this by now.