# If Android is open source, then how did Google ban Huawei from using it?

Tags: google, huawei

Android is open source, it is based on a Linux Kernel which has been modified by a variant of C language.

A few years back there was a big controversy when Google banned Huawei due to some security/privacy issues and then you couldn’t use almost any Google services on it.

So if Android is FOSS, then that doesn’t make any sense. Like anyone should be able to use Android on any device they choose, and what stopped Huawei from continuing to use it?

Comment: Duplicate of [Google's Huawei ban, how will this hit Huawei, since Android is open source?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/212659/44325) but not yet properly answered (the comment thread hints at the real issue)

Comment: Google only prevented access to its proprietary software (Google Apps and Services), not the vanilla Android source code that it releases on the web.

Comment: Android is not FOSS, it never was. Android Open Source Project (AOSP) and Android ecosystem are entirely different things. AOSP cannot be used on device without the hardware-related proprietary parts from OEMs. And it is pretty useless for many - or at least very inconvenient to use, very unproductive, and far less elegant - without the proprietary parts from Google. Unfortunately this is the shady aspect of Google's business. Huawei needs to make huge marketing efforts to fill the gap in latter part.